# Editing the data twice while trying to retain changes for Streamlit data editor when hiding or switching between widgets/pages

Tags: python, dataframe, session-state, streamlit

I have a selectbox with 20 properties (options) in streamlit. Each option displays an editable dataframe when selected. The user should be able to edit the table contents continuously. These changes should persist even if the user selects a different option from the selectbox and switches back to the previous edited option. I tried using '@st.cache' and 'st.sessionstate' options to achieve this. It works but there are couple of issues. Firstly, every time I edit a cell in the dataframe, it has to be entered twice for the changes to get reflected. Secondly, the whole page reloads for every cell edit making it an extremely slow and inefficient process. I want the user to edit the table continuously without reloading the page for every cell edit and the changed should get reflected when they enter it the first time. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.